# country time in laravel system

Tags: laravel, wso2

I work on a course system that has course times I want when the site is opened in a country, the time of the course appears for the user in the real time of the country in which the user is located

Comment: Store everything as utc and display times to users based on their local Timezone.

Answer (score 0):

To convert user time to UTC use following laravel code in your controller method

```
# convert user date provided date string to user date
$user_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_string));

# convert user date to utc date
$utc_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $user_date, $user->timezone);
$utc_date->setTimezone('UTC');

# check the utc date
dd($utc_date);
```

Convert UTC time to User time

```
# using utc date convert date to user date
$user_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $utc_date, 'UTC');
$user_date->setTimezone($user->timezone);

# check the user date
dd($user_date);
```